# Change default user of folder

Tags: linux, chgrp

I'm having a little problem here. So I changed the group of a folder including subfolders via `chgrp -R groupname` and it works all fine but I'm using transmission and pyload to download files into those folders and they both write the files as root in there.

Can I somehow change the default group/user for the specific folder so that it also includes new folders/files?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not recommended to run pyload as root.
You better take a user which has full read/write permissions on the pyload home folder as well as the download folder.

Second, inside the pyLoad-WebUI, you can choose under Settings->Menu->Permissions how pyload should handle file-permissions.

Comment: Hi, how can I make it run as no root user? It is a service doesn't that require root?

Comment: Just run "pyLoadCore --daemon" as your Main-Unix-User. pyLoad runs under the user, you start it with. Don't do "sudo" or something like this.